# API is logging to console more than once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to create a search page for Pathfinder. Below is the code I wrote to try and pull in the data from the api. While trying to just get the fetches to work, I am noticing when I console.log the data returned from the fetches, it is listed more than once.

```
async function getData(){
    const apiKey = "API KEY WITHHELD";

    const actionsURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/action";
    const ancestriesURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/ancestry";
    const ancestryFeaturesURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/ancestryFeature";
    const archetypesURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/archetype";
    const backgroundsURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/background";
    const classesURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/class";
    const classFeaturesURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/classFeature";
    const deitiesURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/deity";
    const equipmentURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/equipment";
    const featsURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/feat";
    const spellsURL = "https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2/spell";

    // Actions
    const actionsResponse = await fetch(actionsURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const actionsData = await actionsResponse.json();

    // Ancestries
    const ancestriesResponse = await fetch(ancestriesURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const ancestriesData = await ancestriesResponse.json();
  

    // Ancestry Features
    const ancestryFeaturesResponse = await fetch(ancestryFeaturesURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const ancestryFeaturesData = await ancestryFeaturesResponse.json();

    // Archetypes
    const archetypesResponse = await fetch(archetypesURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const archetypesData = await archetypesResponse.json();

    // Backgrounds
    const backgroundsResponse = await fetch(backgroundsURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const backgroundsData = await backgroundsResponse.json();

    // Classes
    const classesResponse = await fetch(classesURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const classesData = await classesResponse.json();

    // Class Features
    const classFeaturesResponse = await fetch(classFeaturesURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const classFeaturesData = await classFeaturesResponse.json();

    // Deities
    const deitiesResponse = await fetch(deitiesURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const deitiesData = await deitiesResponse.json();

    // Equipment
    const equipmentResponse = await fetch(equipmentURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const equipmentData = await equipmentResponse.json();

    // Feats
    const featsResponse = await fetch(featsURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const featsData = await featsResponse.json();

    // Spells
    const spellsResponse = await fetch(spellsURL, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': new Headers({
            "Authorization": apiKey,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }),
    });
    const spellsData = await spellsResponse.json();

    // do what you want with actionsData and ancestriesData, etc here
    console.log(actionsData);
    console.log(ancestriesData);
    console.log(ancestryFeaturesData);
    console.log(archetypesData);
    console.log(backgroundsData);
    console.log(classesData);
    console.log(classFeaturesData);
    console.log(deitiesData);
    console.log(equipmentData);
    console.log(featsData);
    //console.log(spellsData);
}

getData();
```

Originally I used a fetch to grab all of the endpoints listed in the main endpoint (see page: https://api.pathfinder2.fr/doc) and then ran a loop to fetch data from each endpoint -- DRY principles and what not.

```
const apiKey = "API KEY WITHHELD";

let pathfinderLibraries = [];

let pathfinder = fetch("https://api.pathfinder2.fr/v1/pf2", {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': new Headers({
        "Authorization": apiKey,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }),
}).then((response) =>  {
    return response.json()
})
.then(data => {
    let pflibraries = data;
    //console.log(pflibraries);

    pflibraries.forEach(pflibrary => {
        pathfinderLibraries.push(pflibrary);

        pathfinderLibraries.forEach( library => {
            fetch(library, {
                'method': 'GET',
                'headers': new Headers({
                    "Authorization": apiKey,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                }),
            }).then((response) =>  {
                return response.json()
            }).then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });

        console.log(pflibrary);
    });
});
```

But this was logging each of the endpoint data multiple times so I decided to try it without the loop. This decreased the amount of times each endpoint data was logged, but the data was still being logged multiple times.

I experimented with changing the location of the console.logs and had 1 of 2 results, either it did not log at all or continued to log multiple times.

As I said previously, I just wanted to create a function with a loop that would iterate through main endpoint that lists the sub-endpoints and fetch the data so I can create a search page for Pathfinder.

Comment: Do you have [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) enabled by any chance? If you have the `getData` call somewhere in the useEffect - then it will be executed 2 times. If not - please, include that info in the question due to it is a spot #1 to check.

Comment: The example with the forEach loop is vanilla js not using react, I popped the code into react as I decided I wanted to use it, but did not do anything else. There is no useEffect being used. But it is using strict mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this block of code

```
pflibraries.forEach(pflibrary => {
    pathfinderLibraries.push(pflibrary);

    pathfinderLibraries.forEach( library => {
```

you traverse through `pflibraries` and each of them you are adding into `pathfinderLibraries`. Right after that you traverse through `pathfinderLibraries`.

This means that after every loop through `pflibraries` your list of libraries in `pathfinderLibraries` will contain `pflibrary` from the current iteration and also from all the previous iterations of `pflibraries`.

To fix the problem you need to remove this `forEach` from the code

```
pathfinderLibraries.forEach( library => {
```

and just call the `fetch` for the `library` in the current iteration.

Comment: Ahhh... thank you, I will edit my code and try it out!

Comment: Damn my code was so close haha! Yes, it solved my problem! Thanks again! Marked as the Solution.